# How to Left Strip Only "one" Zero from string in Python

Tags: python, format, strip

I have a string of numbers in this format "IIDDDDDDDD" where "I" are the integers and "D" are the decimals and the string always contains 10 numbers.

I need to format it as II.DDDDDDDD but some times after formatting the number is eg: 00.12345678. I tried using .lstrip('0') but it removes both zeros before the decimal separator and it returns ".12345678" instead of "0.12345678"

```
        df_operacoes['PU Parte'] = df_operacoes['PU Parte'].map(lambda x: f'{x[:2]}.{x[2:]}')
        df_operacoes['PU Parte'] = df_operacoes['PU Parte'].str.lstrip('0')
        df_operacoes['PU ContraParte'] = df_operacoes['PU ContraParte'].map(lambda x: f'{x[:2]}.{x[2:]}')
        df_operacoes['PU ContraParte'] = df_operacoes['PU ContraParte'].str.lstrip('0')
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it's unclear why you'd choose a representation like this to begin with (perhaps you didn't and you just have to work with it), the problem is very straightforward and so can the solution be:

```
if df_operacoes['PU Parte'][:2] == '00':
    df_operacoes['PU Parte'] = df_operacoes['PU Parte'][1:]
```

There's nicer solutions possible for more variations of this representation (for example if you also have `IIIDDDDDDD` cases, etc. - but that doesn't appear to be the case.

Your comment indicated this was about a `DataFrame` - then the below would work:

```
from pandas import DataFrame

df_operacoes['PU Parte'] = df_operacoes['PU Parte'].apply(lambda s: f'{s[1:2]}.{s[2:]}' if s.startswith('00') else f'{s[:2]}.{s[2:]}')
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer.

As you said, i already receive data in this format unfortunately. I tried your sugestion but it raised an error:

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: Ah, I might have guessed from the `df_` prefix, but it wasn't clear from you question that the value is in fact the column of a `pandas` `Dataframe`. Updated the answer.

Comment: Sorry for not being so clear on the question. I tried the second solution and it worked when the number is 0.xxxxxxxx, but then its 1.xxxxxxxx the mask returns 01.xxxxxxxx. I merged you both solutions and it worked (maybe it's not the best way as you said).

`df_operacoes['PU Parte'] = df_operacoes['PU Parte'].apply(lambda x: f'{x[1:2]}.{x[2:]}' if x.startswith('00') else f'{x[:2]}.{x[2:]}')

        for x, y in df_operacoes.iterrows():
            if y['PU Parte'][:2] == '01':
                df_operacoes.at[x, 'PU Parte'] = df_operacoes.at[x, 'PU Parte'].lstrip("0")`